# Stock API - QTY and out of stock

Tags: stock

I have an integration with an ERP system which is pushing stock qty to Magento2.

The problem is that if the item qty becomes 0 Magento puts it out of stock, when the ERP updates the qty to say 10 the item remains out of stock. I would expect Magento to deal with this.

Potentially we could get the ERP system to pass in stock across to Magento but we want Magento to control that because there might be back orders on Magento etc

Thanks

Comment: @are you updating multiple products ? please share which API you are using.